# Preparing multi class from multi value of raster data?

Tags: multi-band, multi-values

How can I prepare a specific band for each value in the below photo?

[image]

This raster file is a result of classification which I prepared in ENVI and for some edits I imported it in ArcGIS. after modification I imported the TIFF file  in ENVI for providing confusion matrix, but it was imported as 1 band. I need multi bands of this file to provide a confusion matrix in ENVI.

I am beginner in using ArcGIS and it could be a great help to guide me and give me a solution.

Comment: If by "multi class" you mean merging bands, than [Reclassify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) is the tool you're after, otherwise please try to be more clear what you mean.

Comment: How can I prepare a specific bans for each value of raster file whicj includes different values?This raster file is a result of classification which I prepared in ENVI and for some edits I imported it in ArcGIS. after modification I imported the TIFF file in ENVI for providing confusion matrix, but it was imported as 1 band. I need multi bands of this file to provide a confusion matrix in ENVI.

I am beginner in using ArcGIS and it could be a great help to guide me and give me a solution.